# How to pause reading a text file at onclick of button and resume it when Onclick button in mfc vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

How to pause reading a text file at onclick of button and resume it when Onclick button in mfc vc++?

The file is opened as below 
CFileException fileException;

```
    if (readFile.Open(strFilePath, CFile::modeRead, &fileException)
{
while (readFile.ReadString(strLine))
{
...
}

}
```

Comment: this is running in a different thread?

Comment: I  am using  visual c++ with mfc so i have used following tags

Answer (score 0):

Try tro move that code to another thread, I *think* with any solution you'll have to fight with [reentrancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29) if this code is inside the main thread but you have to peek messages from message queue. Using a thread you can [suspend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12f04d1s.aspx) it or use some [synchronization primitive](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node31.html) to manage its wait.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the "reading" to a separate thread is definitely the best way. However, you can add the following function to allow other events to happen while reading:

```
void DoEvents()
{
  MSG msg;
  while( ::PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
  {
    ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
    ::DispatchMessage ( &msg );
  }
}
```

Assuming you have a volatile flag in your code to indicating pausing/resuming, you can do something like:

```
while (readFile.ReadString(strLine)) 
{ 
  while( this->m_bPause == TRUE )
  {
    ::Sleep( 100 ); // Adjust as necessary
    DoEvents();
  }

  // continue reading...
}
```

This should work, but you may notice the app be a little unresponsive during the loop. Hope this helps.